# Changes not taking effect when class is removed from theme.css - MVC5 ASP.NET

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application, that currently has a Theme.css I need to remove a class on the theme, I have removed the class, but when I have merged my branch into the default branch the changes are not taking effect.

I have checked in the BundleConfig in App_Start this is what I have:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/theme").Include(
       "~/skin/default_skin/css/theme.css",
       "~/admin-tools/admin-forms/css/admin-forms.css",
       "~/plugins/select2/css/core.css"));
```

Now in `Content/theme the theme.css` folder is not included in the project. But I have made my changes in the file: `/skin/default_skin/css/theme.css` but then when I merge my branch into the live site the change is undone.

But `~/Content/theme.css` is excluded from the project.

Comment: It is hard to determine the cause, especially if it is reproduced only on the production site. First, I suggest you open Developer Tools in a browser (press F12), check what CSS links are rendered in HTML page markup. Next, open the 'Network' DevTools tab and check what content is obtained from the server by these URLs

Comment: @Vladimir I have check what CSS links are rendered, they match the files that I have removed the class on, I have built the project on a local branch, checked the sources and network tab and the class has been removed.

I will try and deploy it to the live site to see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was due to the way MVC is bundled in.Net also factoring in the way the minification is happening. It was bundling the theme, but any changes to it where excluded from the project build, so I think when I was changing the files it was ignoring the changes, building it then minifying the files.